# Date formatter returns different date strings in iOS 8 and iOS 9

Tags: ios, date

`EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz` is the date formatter used in  my application . The I run this on iOS9 the date string returned is **Fri, 27 Nov 2015 16:38:47 IST** and in iOS8 its **Fri, 27 Nov 2015 16:44:04 GMT+5:30**. Anyone whose how to solve this.

Comment: Try by setting locale as `en_US_POSIX` on your date formatter.

Comment: You know, that this is the same time or?

Comment: Check your Language and Region settings are the same in both cases. Might be that on iOS8 you had the language as English (UK) and something different now, or perhaps more likely, on iOS8 you had the region set as United Kingdom and have the region set as something else now. I haven't specifically tested to verify, but I would expect that kind of a difference to occur if these settings are changed.

Comment: please show your code for us to be 100% sure that you pass in the correct date format string at the correct place.

Comment: setting en_US_POSIX fixed the issue